# How to import Tensorflow Lite interpreter in Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

How can we import the *tensorflow lite* libraries in our *Android Project*?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentations](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tfmobile/linking_libs) says:

> For Android, you just need to link in a Java library contained in a JAR file called libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar. There are three ways to include this functionality in your program:
>
> Include the jcenter AAR which contains it, as in this example app
>
> Download the nightly precompiled version from ci.tensorflow.org.
>
> Build the JAR file yourself using the instructions in our Android
>   GitHub repo

I would chose the [first](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tfmobile/build.gradle#L59-L65) one because it is easier and more maintainable. You should add the dependencies to your `build.gradle` (module: app):

```
repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to import `tensorflow-lite` in your project make the following changes in your app `build.gralde` file

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        //...
    }
    //...
    //make sure you add this 
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
        noCompress "lite"
    }
}

dependencies {
    //... other dependencies
    //add this line
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy go around with this is to use demo Android code templates where you can get pre-configured app code with Tensorflow lite and there is just a small change needed which is to update/change the model with `.tflite` file extension (generally named as `detect.tflite` in demo templates )and `labels.txt` file if required as well.

both files will be present in the same folder in the asset folder or in some `ml` named folder.

It's the best approach for beginners in the TF lite android app approach who aren't android dev.

Answer (score 0):

**to implement the tensor flow interpreter you need to add the library below in your gradle**

```
// for object Detector
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
```